# SelectedIndexChanged event occures on every combo box whcih in on Form

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am working on VB.NET windows application.

I have added three combo-box on my form. The problem is , if I change 
one-combo-box's index i.e. SelectedIndexChanged event occur for that combo box,

but same time SelectedIndexChanged  event occurs of every other combo box which is present on that form.

Whats the problem, I am confused,am I missing something ?

```
 Private Sub LoadBenNamesInComboBox()
        DataLoaded = False
        Dim oBenname As New BenDetails
        oBenname.LoadAll()


        cmbNEFTBenNames.DataSource = oBenname
        cmbNEFTBenNames.DisplayMember = "NameOfBen"
        cmbNEFTBenNames.ValueMember = "ID"

        cmbRTGSBenNames.DataSource = oBenname
        cmbRTGSBenNames.DisplayMember = "NameOfBen"
        cmbRTGSBenNames.ValueMember = "ID"

        cmbIMPSBen.DataSource = oBenname
        cmbIMPSBen.DisplayMember = "NameOfBen"
        cmbIMPSBen.ValueMember = "ID"

        DataLoaded = True

    End Sub

     Private Sub cmbNEFTBenNames_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbNEFTBenNames.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmbIMPSBen_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbIMPSBen.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub


    Private Sub cmbRTGSBenNames_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbRTGSBenNames.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like they're sharing the same `DataSource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are binding the drop down boxes back to the datasource, using the combo boxes datasource property.

When you select a value in one of the drop downs it automatically updates the others to the same value.

Instead you could set the data sources to a copy or array of the oBenName object.

e.g. if BenDetails is a LIST or something that uses the ToArray function you could do:

```
 Private Sub LoadBenNamesInComboBox()
    DataLoaded = False
    Dim oBenname As New BenDetails
    oBenname.LoadAll()


    cmbNEFTBenNames.DataSource = oBenname.ToArray
    cmbNEFTBenNames.DisplayMember = "NameOfBen"
    cmbNEFTBenNames.ValueMember = "ID"

    cmbRTGSBenNames.DataSource = oBenname.ToArray
    cmbRTGSBenNames.DisplayMember = "NameOfBen"
    cmbRTGSBenNames.ValueMember = "ID"

    cmbIMPSBen.DataSource = oBenname.ToArray
    cmbIMPSBen.DisplayMember = "NameOfBen"
    cmbIMPSBen.ValueMember = "ID"

    DataLoaded = True

End Sub
```